# Image MKOverlay crashes on rotate

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to add a geographically large (~1km) single image to a MkMapView as an overlay. Eventually I want to update this image every second or so.

I have created a MkOverlay subclass based on code I found on here, and add it to the mapkit view. It draws in the correct place, it moves and scales with the movement of the map but if I try to rotate it the screen locks and it starts increasing memory at a rate that in my last test was 10Mb / second, which may be related to the size of the image. This is constant until it runs out of memory or I quit it.
This is on the simulator or a real device. It is not calling any of my code or producing any output in this time, and as I am very new to swift (< 1 month) I am at a bit of a loss to know how else I can debug it.

I have copied this same application, just changing the minimum I need to change (ie, UI to NS) to run as a map application, and the whole application runs and can rotate properly.

I made a stripped down application that contained the minimum possible code, that also crashes.

```
class ImageOverlay : NSObject, MKOverlay {

    let image:UIImage
    let boundingMapRect: MKMapRect
    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(image: UIImage, rect: MKMapRect) {
        self.image = image
        self.boundingMapRect = rect
        var coord = rect.origin
        coord.x += rect.size.width / 2
        coord.y += rect.size.height / 2;
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.x, longitude: coord.y)
    }
}

class ImageOverlayRenderer : MKOverlayRenderer {

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext)
    {
        guard let overlay = self.overlay as? ImageOverlay else {
            return
        }
        let rect = self.rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)
        context.saveGState()
        context.setAlpha(0.6)
        context.draw(overlay.image.cgImage!, in: rect, byTiling: false)
        context.flush()
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var imgOver: ImageOverlay?

    let mapViewDelegate = MapViewDelegate()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame:.zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.delegate = mapViewDelegate 
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  
        view.mapType = .hybrid
        addImage(to: view)
    }
}

 extension MapView {
    
    func addImage(to view: MKMapView) {
        if !view.overlays.isEmpty {
            view.removeOverlays(view.overlays)
        }
        guard let img = imgOver else { return }
        let mapRect = img.boundingMapRect
        view.setVisibleMapRect(mapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100), animated: true)
        view.addOverlay(img)
    }
}

class MapViewDelegate: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        ImageOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var imageOverlay: ImageOverlay?

    var body: some View {
        MapView(imgOver:$imageOverlay)
                .onAppear {
                    let image = UIImage(named: "portland.png")!
                    let p1 =  MKMapPoint( CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.564479946138384, -2.4423953407134054))
                    let p2 = MKMapPoint( CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.57264968724567, -2.415437272738347))
                    let bounds = MKMapRect(x: fmin(p1.x,p2.x), y: fmin(p1.y,p2.y), width: fabs(p1.x-p2.x), height: fabs(p1.y-p2.y));
                    self.showImage(image:image, bounds:bounds )
        }
    }
}

private extension ContentView {
    func showImage(image:UIImage?, bounds:MKMapRect) {
        if image == nil {
            return
        }
        self.imageOverlay = ImageOverlay(image:image!, rect:bounds)
    }
}
```

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong or how better to debug a memory loss outside my code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it, it was the MapView UIRepresentable example that I got from here.
I suspect the view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints caused the issue. For reference for anyone else trying to do this, I replaced the MapView with:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var imgOver: ImageOverlay?

    let mapViewDelegate = MapViewDelegate()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let view = MKMapView(frame:.zero)
        view.delegate = mapViewDelegate
        view.mapType = .hybrid
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        addImage(to: view)
    }
}
```

Now the overlay works fully as expected for all uses.